# Make visible filtered rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following jQuery DataTable

```
ID  |  IP Address   |Channel    |Format

 1  |192.168.9.41   |News 1     | HD    
 2  |192.168.9.45   |Sports 1   | HD    
 3  |192.168.9.47   |Movie 1    | SD    
 4  |192.168.9.48   |ESPN HD    | HD    
 5  |192.168.9.49   |Talk       | SD
```

And applied the filter, let's say 'HD'. So, the data in table is as follow,

```
ID  |  IP Address   |Channel    |Format

 1  |192.168.9.41   |News 1     | HD    
 2  |192.168.9.45   |Sports 1   | HD    
 4  |192.168.9.48   |ESPN HD    | HD
```

The code to do that is below:

```
$scope.filterValue = function(){
    var table = $('#poolDetail').DataTable();
    table.search($scope.currentFilter).draw();
}
```

After this filter, I need to include the Channel 'Talk' that was hidden by filter.

How could I add a single row to the table?

Comment: Can you maybe filter by both, HD and the Talk Channel?

Comment: Hi Hanlet! Thanks for your response. That's no the idea because, one of the filter is using the search box of jquery DataTables and the other one (Talk) is inherited from other pages and I have to apply it after the first one was applied.

Comment: So you want the filter to be applied but display certain rows despite the filter?

Comment: Yes, after filtering, add some rows that are not longer visibles because they did not match the initial filter but will match the second one I need to apply manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else matters this case, I have resolved it just adding a new hidden column to the table and dynamically add the filter string as a value of the column for all rows that I need to add as visible and originally did not match the filter.

The piece of code to add values to the hidden column is the following.

```
    $scope.addIndividualFilteringPrograms = function(){
        var programsToAdd = filteredProgramService.getIndividualFiltering();
        if(programsToAdd.length > 0){
             for(var i=0;i<programsToAdd.length;i++){
                var table = $('#ProgramsTable').DataTable();
                table.column(3).data().each(
                    function ( value, index ) {
                         if(value === programsToAdd[i].name){
                             var rightIndex =  table.rows().eq(0)[index];           
                             table.cell(rightIndex, 10).data($scope.currentFilter).draw();
                         }
                    }
                );
              }
          }
    }
```

(The number 10 is the index of the hidden column and $scope.currentFilter is the filter applied in seach box.)
After I add this values, I got the new rows visibles.
Thanks.